# How to launch VSCode chrome debugger using HTTPS proxy

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, https, vscode-debugger

I've launched chrome from VSCode before without an SSL proxy, so I'm guessing that is at the root of my issues.  Here's my VSCode launch.json configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "pwa-chrome",
    "url": "https://example.com:8000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

I'm using webpack in watch mode which is launching on port 8000, and I'm running an Express https server proxy.

The launch config works fine to launch the url, but it does not activate breakpoints within VSCode.

I could not find any information on launch configuration specific to SSL.

Is there anything I can try to get the debugger working properly, and get these breakpoints activated?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same need.

Comment: @GarySheppard Please see my answer. You should be able to do it no problem. I'm debugging Angular. Only one issue I'm facing is my API server is node also running self-signed certificate, I'm able to iron out certificate issues in Postman and Chrome accessing API, but VSC Chrome always returns `name: 'HttpErrorResponse', status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'https://localhost:3001/whatever'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to start **httpS Chrome** debugging after some painful times, I'm using certificate generated by openSSL. Key is to make Chrome accept my certificate, tried so many solutions, finally here is the super easy way, type in this in Chrome's address box:

> chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

then make sure Enable it
[image]

My launch.json:

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "F5 against localhost",
    "port": 4201,
    "url": "https://localhost:4200",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```