# Status 0, StatusText: Unknown Error, Name: HttpErrorResponse

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssl-certificate

Localhost development with VSC, Angular 11 and node/Express API, using self-signed certificate of OpenSSL. I'm able to iron out all issues including Postman and standalone Chrome, see details in [my answer of this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269964/how-to-launch-vscode-chrome-debugger-using-https-proxy), except when Angular making a call to API `https://localhost:3001/whatever` always got the error in Title. (Postman and standalone Chrome work)

F12, Network reveals it's not my code on Angular and node, it's the cert.
[image]

My launch.json:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach to a running Chrome @4200",
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222,
        "urlFilter": "https://localhost:4200/*",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "F5 against localhost",
        "port": 4201,
        "url": "https://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

Why am I having two entries? App is using 3rd-party authentication such as Google. Before figured out how to debug using `F5`, I always got "Couldn’t sign you in. You browser is not secure. Try …" . `Attach` was my solution along with `pwa-chrome`. Later I figured out to use legacy Chrome for F5.

VSC About:

```
Version: 1.57.1 (user setup)
Commit: 507ce72a4466fbb27b715c3722558bb15afa9f48
Date: 2021-06-17T13:28:07.755Z
Electron: 12.0.7
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041
```

Standalone Chrome is  91.0.4472.114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Chrome brought up by F5 doesn't have the setting already-set in standalone. So, simply `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` and Enable it.